# convert html to image java

Tags: java, html, image

I have a String html and I want to create an image. qui contains the html I found this methode:

```
JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();  
    pane.setEditable(false);  
    pane.setContentType("text/html");  
    pane.setText(printHtmlTable());  
    pane.setSize(pane.getPreferredSize());
    /* 
    * Create a BufferedImage 
    */  
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(pane.getWidth(), pane  
    .getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);  
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();  
    /* 
    * Have the image painted by SwingUtilities 
    */  
    pane.paint(g);
    g.dispose();
```

[image: the image generated by the code]

[image: the browser look]

But the image result it has a bad resolution and the color is different from the look in the navigator, can you give me another methode?

Comment: Can you just use the Robot class and take a screenshot?

Comment: this method works and looks great for me, maybe post here the exact case when it doesn't looks as wanted to?

Comment: @higuaro how i can do it?